# Hot Swap SSD and Windows Installation?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, crash, rebuild

I'M planning to buy SSD hot swap 2.5 - 3.5 unit like this:

http://www.ebay.ie/itm/111546698822?...84.m1439.l2649

I want to create 2 (or might be 3) swappable SSD drives with Windows OS on it.
One SSD for me, settings to play my games and convert videos and to do other HC stuff - a lot's of pressure.

Another one for my missus, quiet one - settings for facebook and skype and safe browsing

Might be some stage in future I'll make one SSD for kids, for more safe browsing and so on.

Ideally everyone using them own swappable SSD - OS and settings.

Reason:
Two days ago I managed completely to crash our PC and needed to completely rebuild whole OS and drivers and settings.
Almost whole day went by restoring all those important family pictures and videos ( puppy linux method ) - a lot of data and a lot of time..

So I came up with this "brilliant" idea to keep existing 3.5 HDD's inside the PC only for file storage (photos and videos and music).
OS to be installed on SSD ,one drive for every user group (me, wife, kids, might be one for random visitors)
Example - if I'll manage to crash my OS system again , she still can log in to her Windows with her own SSD and could not to be bothered.

Would it work?

Cheers!

Comment: No reason it wouldn't work - so long as everybody realises you cannot hot-swap the running OS drive… however, I'm sure a good backup strategy would be cheaper & simpler in the long run. For pure paranoia, always keep a spare drive handy & you can be back up & running in an hour, even after a total boot drive loss.

Answer (score 0):

I have small SSD-disk, with multi-boot on other conventional disk, but want to have the swap file from the other OS boot (i.e. the swap file is shared).

So I have shrinked my SSD disk, and for each boot I have Swap with "Max & min" set to min "x" & max "x" + 2 MB, so itis a fixed size and doesn't waste resources changing size and also takes advantage of the speed on SSD-disk.

I have a number of partitions made with the Windows built-in disk management tools "Windows" which you can get to via `%windir%\System32\diskmgmt.msc`